# SQL from a given value, get all top and bottom rows until this value changes

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a local SQL Express where I am doing some queries from vb.net. However, no success with following one. If I have something like,

```
dateTime              var1  

2015/08/10 18:35:00   1
2015/08/10 18:36:00   1
2015/08/10 18:37:20   2
2015/08/10 18:38:00   2
2015/08/10 18:39:00   2
2015/08/10 18:40:00   2
2015/08/10 18:39:20   1 
2015/08/10 18:40:00   2
```

from a known dateTime and var1, I would like to get all top and bottom rows until var1 changes.
For example, from "2015/08/10 18:38:00","2" I should get,

```
2015/08/10 18:37:20   2
2015/08/10 18:38:00   2
2015/08/10 18:39:00   2
2015/08/10 18:40:00   2
```

Comment: Would you like to do this in SQL or do it in VB.Net?

Comment: I am programing in vb .net but I am asking for the SQL string

Comment: Is it on a database or in a datagridview? Or where is the data currently?

Comment: data is in local SQL Express. I am already doing queries but no success with this one.

Comment: Select var1 from yourTable Where yourDateValue = '2015/08/10 18:38:00'; 
Select * from yourTable where var1 = the value from the first query.

Comment: @Mort, this will select all values where var1 has the provided value... Not my question. Please note that can be more rows thas has same value but ONLY want the group that provided dateTime is included. So your solution  will include last row from the example and this one must be excluded

Comment: How are the rows ordered?  SQL tables have no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: @Gordon, ordered by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there are more elegant ways of accomplishing this, but I will take my best shot:  this assumes that you are looking for an unbroken chain of `Var1` values with at least one record per minute.

One thing that I couldn't figure out was how to crawl in both directions (Low and High) based on the one-minute-gap theory, so I use a pair of recursive `CTE`s and then `SELECT` from both.

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME = '2015/08/10 18:38:00'
DECLARE @Var1 INT = 2

;WITH 
    Data AS 
      (
        SELECT '2015/08/10 18:35:00' AS D,   1 AS V UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2015/08/10 18:36:00' AS D,   1 AS V UNION ALL
        SELECT '2015/08/10 18:37:20' AS D,   2 AS V UNION ALL
        SELECT '2015/08/10 18:38:00' AS D,   2 AS V UNION ALL
        SELECT '2015/08/10 18:39:00' AS D,   2 AS V UNION ALL
        SELECT '2015/08/10 18:40:00' AS D,   2 AS V UNION ALL
        SELECT '2015/08/10 18:39:20' AS D,   1 AS V UNION ALL
        SELECT '2015/08/10 18:40:00' AS D,   2 AS V 
      ),
    Low AS 
      (
        SELECT D, V 
        FROM Data 
        WHERE D = @DateTime AND V = @Var1

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT Data.D, Data.V 
        FROM 
            Data 
             INNER JOIN 
            Low ON 
                DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Data.D, Low.D) = 1 AND 
                Data.V = Low.V 
      ), 
    High AS 
      (
        SELECT D, V 
        FROM Data 
        WHERE D = @DateTime AND V = @Var1

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT Data.D, Data.V 
        FROM 
            Data 
             INNER JOIN 
            High ON 
                DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Data.D, High.D) = -1 AND 
                Data.V = High.V 
      )


SELECT *
FROM Low  

UNION  

SELECT *
FROM High 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Next query selects bounds of fixed value and then selects all rows between them:

```
 SELECT * FROM Test 
WHERE id < (
  SELECT IFNULL((SELECT a.id FROM Test a, Test b, Test c
  WHERE 
    (a.id = b.id + 1 AND a.var != b.var) 
  AND 
    c.id < a.id
  AND 
    c.date = '2015/08/10 18:38:00'
  AND
    c.var = 2
  ORDER BY a.id LIMIT 1), (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM Test))
) AND id > (
  SELECT IFNULL((SELECT a.id FROM Test a, Test b, Test c
  WHERE 
    (a.id = b.id - 1 AND a.var != b.var) 
  AND 
    c.id > a.id
  AND 
    c.date = '2015/08/10 18:38:00' 
  AND
    c.var = 2
  ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 1), (SELECT MIN(id) - 1 FROM Test))
);
```

I hope it solves your problem.